# CuteWebUI.Uploader (Ajax Uploader)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Q.1. When a image file is uploaded via AjaxUplaoder of CuteWebUI.Uploader it saves file like this

```
persisted.057fe17e-9707-4f3a-91b7-250239b19c2f.10.JPG.resx
```

in which "10.jpg" is Image file name and Other "persisted.057fe17e-9707-4f3a-91b7-250239b19c2f.10.JPG.resx" I dont know what is this?

Kindly help me to extract file name from this given format "persisted.057fe17e-9707-4f3a-91b7-250239b19c2f.10.JPG.resx" so that I can show image on Image Control of ASP.Net that is uploaded image file via this Ajax Uploader.  This ajax uploader's property 'args.filename' gives file name on 'FileUploaded' event.

Answer (score 1):

look here for the solution of your problem: http://ajaxuploader.com/document/scr/html/How-to-save-uploaded-file.htm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link is not enough, you should try to describe the solution.